# IOS Device Farm Appium Webdriverio issues

Tags: ios, appium, ios13, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

My team is facing an issue regarding running the tests on Ios device, They are running very slow took around 19 mins per device, on some devices where ios is 13 application is not opened. ON IOS 13 the application is installed but WDA is not installed and also the app is not opened.

Locally we have Xcode 11.1, node 11.6.0, appium 1.17.1
all things work fine and fastly over the local environment.
Just FYI Android its working perfect took 7 mins for the device farm to run the whole test.

The YAML file which we are using is this the latest one provided by aws device farm.

```
version: 0.1

# Phases are collection of commands that get executed on Device Farm.
phases:
  # The install phase includes commands that install dependencies that your tests use.
  # Default dependencies for testing frameworks supported on Device Farm are already installed.
  install:
    commands:
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.17.1
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
      - echo "Node version"
      - node --version
      - echo "NPM version"
      - npm --version
      - echo "Installing wdio globally"
      - npm install -g webdriverio @wdio/cli

      - >-
        if [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 15 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2;
        else
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID;
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1;
        fi


  pre_test:
    commands:

      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"usePrebuiltWDA\": true, \"derivedDataPath\":\"$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH\",
        \"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\",
        \"automationName\":\"XCUITest\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  # The test phase includes commands that run your test suite execution.
  test:
    commands:

      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - npm run test:ios
```

[Link for *Project*](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/77793338-6ba9-4bc7-8a8a-9ca3eccd8ab8/runs/02e0ce83-09ec-4603-b0d7-f21acbbc8cee)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13.3.1 there is a known issue where apps don't open while using Appium and has been fixed on 13.4. More details on the issue here - https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13927